# Elasticsearch Primary Shards not balanced

Tags: elasticsearch

I noticed a strange behaviour in my elasitcsearch cluster. As you can see on the screenshot below (it shows the "kopf"-plugin), most of the primary shards are located on the nl-1 server. I thought, that elasitcsearch balanced the primary shards evenly over all servers. Am I wrong or why is this happening?

Thank you for your help.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont think balance of primaries is a focus of ES.

[See this github issues question about it here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3293)

There is a cluster settings you can tweak to nudge towards balancing them.

[cluster.routing.allocation.balance.primary](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html)

Comment: this has probably moved [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html) for elasticsearch 2.3+

Comment: See also the more recent https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/41543.